# Need help with Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, atheros

Guys I couldn't get my wifi working. I've worked for long using just lan. But, tomorrow, I urgently need working wifi. Help :))

Thing I've tried:

- Checked bios - wifi enabled
- Tried clicking fn + wifi button several times

My output for `lspci | grep Wireless` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)(rev 01)
```

Command `iwconfig` show my lan, but not wifi.

Command `uname -r` output:

`4.2.0-36-generic`

And ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Advices I've found on the net didn't help, ready to provide any output, hope for your help ;)

Thanks. Regards.

**Update:**
Output for:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet [1969:2060] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:396b]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

**Update:**

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 07 Jun 2016 16:46 EEST +0300

Booted last: 07 Jun 2016 14:45 EEST +0300

Script from: 26 May 2016 21:56 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet [1969:2060] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:396b]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b1c1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 143360  0 
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              741376  1 ath9k
cfg80211              552960  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
ideapad_laptop         24576  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  1 ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:459757 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:310387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:282567338 (282.5 MB)  TX bytes:28380101 (28.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       869     1  0 14:45 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            atl1c
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.101
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Kiev (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     681B59FC4C4EB63D7B98108
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        88:C2:A3:E9:92:3B:E7:84:6A:02:95:4D:3D:CF:D2:46:B2:C2:07:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     619327754B562F78060585E
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        88:C2:A3:E9:92:3B:E7:84:6A:02:95:4D:3D:CF:D2:46:B2:C2:07:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     B60D8B6E494EC584155DC34
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        88:C2:A3:E9:92:3B:E7:84:6A:02:95:4D:3D:CF:D2:46:B2:C2:07:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     F1417AD8012BEEF1598B307
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        88:C2:A3:E9:92:3B:E7:84:6A:02:95:4D:3D:CF:D2:46:B2:C2:07:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     507FBE319B9E7D3A3EF5BA9
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        88:C2:A3:E9:92:3B:E7:84:6A:02:95:4D:3D:CF:D2:46:B2:C2:07:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     51BFE91AA49B49C5AD3C396
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        88:C2:A3:E9:92:3B:E7:84:6A:02:95:4D:3D:CF:D2:46:B2:C2:07:9A
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x2060 (atl1c)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x002b (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   20.453166] atl1c 0000:03:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Update3:

```
Version: 36CN19WW(V2.05)
Version: Lenovo G565                     
Version: Base Board Version
Version: Chassis Version
String: Compiler Version: VC 9.0
Version: AMD Athlon(tm) II P360 Dual-Core Processor
```

Comment: Edit the question to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all` thanks

Comment: Is there another switch on the computer to enable/disable wifi?  The rfkill results show a hard block which is usually caused by a switch and can't be fixed with FN combos in most cases

Comment: I don't see it visually, maybe it can be a jumper on the motherboard ?

Comment: See the [wireless info script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) and edit to add results

Comment: Is that all of the report?  It seems to be missing a lot of info

Comment: Sorry, my bad ;)

Comment: That is wireless-info, the file containing results is wireless-info.txt

Comment: ohh... cant be ;) updated

Answer (score 1):

My Lenovo G50 has an airplane mode button (airplane icon on F7 key). Hitting Fn+F7 turns off my wifi. That might explain his wlan "hard blocked" status.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no reaction on Fn+F7

Answer (score 0):

I would first check your restricted drivers in the software sources settings window. Then I would boot into a live disk of Ubuntu (if your system was upgraded) or Fedora and see if either identifies your wifi and works. If neither works, and you have an extra HDD and a windows disk, try installing that on the extra drive and see if windows can use it after installing the driver (more of a computer shop test).

If none of that works and your WiFi did work at some point, then you may have a bad WiFi card. You could go to a computer shop and ask to try any extra that they have (they have a bunch) and to buy whichever works. Don't let them take it into the back, and swap it out on the counter. It is faster and they will charge extra just to walk it into the back.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Lenovo laptop that uses the ideapad_laptop module, do the following as a temporary solution

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad_laptop.conf
```

and reboot

The ideapad_laptop module has a bug that incorrectly reads the rfkill state on some Lenovo computers.  The kernel developers have added a quirks table to the module so that rfkill will work correctly.

I may be able to make a better solution with the results from

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -i version
```

Please edit your answer to add the result

Comment: Updated main post

Comment: Did the blacklist work?  I don't remember seeing this issue with a G series before.  Is there a harware switch on the laptop?

Comment: Nope, black list didn't help. I don't see hardware switch visually, it should be in the outer space, right? And maybe this info might help: I've reinstalled Ubuntu couple days ago, and during install process Ubuntu was able to use WiFi without any dances...

Comment: Have you gone into BIOS and reset to defaults?